# How to make radio button checked row come first in the kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in which one of the column is a radio button.
I want to display the kendo grid in such way that the radio button checked row should come in the first row of the displayed kendo grid using java script since i am using java script for kendo grid.

This is how i accessed the checked row

```
var gridAssociatedUsersData = gridAssociatedUsers.dataSource.data();

                    var checkedRow = $("input:checked", gridAssociatedUsers.tbody).closest("tr");
                    var item = gridAssociatedUsers.dataItem(checkedRow);
```

But i couldn't display this row first in the kendo grid.
Please help me out for the problem. Thanks.

Comment: you can change the dataSource so that the checked column rows are on top

Comment: Thanks harsh. In the end it was rather so simple that i just needed to sort the data source. (: